# C Programming printing large negative numbers

Tags: c

Im new to programming but im in a programming course to start introducing it. Problem is they dont teach it they just give us things to do. We need to create functions to calculate the amount of cents someone has based upon the number of coins and dollars a person has (which is inputted through the user). I have no idea what im doing or if im even using the function prototype right but when i run my program i dont get any errors but it just prints a large negative number. Heres what i have, i know its long sorry, but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include </home/TU/tue64800/include/myheader.h>

#define PENNYCOIN      1
#define NICKELCOIN     5
#define DIMECOIN      10
#define QUARTERCOIN   25
#define HALFCOIN      50
#define DOLLAR       100

int penny_coin_worth( int number_of_pennies );  
int nickel_coin_worth( int number_of_nickels );
int dime_coin_worth( int number_of_dimes );
int quarter_coin_worth( int number_of_quarters );                  
int half_coin_worth( int number_of_half );             
int dollar_coin_worth( int number_of_dollars );            
int total_worth ( int number_of_pennies, int number_of_nickels, int number_of_dimes,
int number_of_quarters, int number_of_half, int number_of_dollars );

int number_of_pennies, number_of_nickels, number_of_dimes, number_of_quarters,
number_of_half, number_of_dollars;
int total;

int main (void)
{
printf( "This program was written by %s.\n", PROGRAMMER_NAME );

printf( "Enter number of pennies:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_pennies);

printf( "Enter number of nickels:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_nickels);

printf( "Enter number of dimes:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_dimes);

printf( "Enter number of quarters:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_quarters);

printf( "Enter number of half dollars:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_half);

printf( "Enter number of dollars:\n");
scanf( "%lf", &number_of_dollars);

penny_coin_worth (number_of_pennies);
nickel_coin_worth (number_of_nickels);
dime_coin_worth (number_of_dimes);
quarter_coin_worth (number_of_quarters);
half_coin_worth (number_of_half);
dollar_coin_worth (number_of_dollars);

total_worth ( number_of_pennies, number_of_nickels, number_of_dimes,   
number_of_quarters, number_of_half, number_of_dollars );

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int penny_coin_worth (int number_of_pennies)
{
    return ( number_of_pennies * PENNYCOIN);
}

int nickel_coin_worth (int number_of_nickels)
{
    return ( number_of_nickels * NICKELCOIN);
}

int dime_coin_worth (int number_of_dimes)
{
    return ( number_of_dimes * DIMECOIN);
}

int quarter_coin_worth (int number_of_quarters)
{
    return ( number_of_quarters * QUARTERCOIN);
}

int half_coin_worth (int number_of_half)
{
    return ( number_of_half * HALFCOIN );
}

int dollar_coin_worth (int number_of_dollars)
{
    return ( number_of_dollars * DOLLAR);
}

int total_worth ( int number_of_pennies, int number_of_nickels, int number_of_dimes,  
int number_of_quarters, int number_of_half, int number_of_dollars)
{
printf("The number of cents is%lf\n", (number_of_pennies * PENNYCOIN +    
number_of_nickels *  NICKELCOIN + number_of_dimes * DIMECOIN + number_of_quarters *  
QUARTERCOIN +  number_of_half * HALFCOIN + number_of_dollars * DOLLAR)*.01);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Please write an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: %lf is for double.  use %d for int.

Answer (score 3):

Read up on [printf Format Specifiers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html). As Guy Sirton said, your mistake is to use `%lf` to read in an `int` (in `scanf`), when those are different types. You should use `%d` for `int`s.

In future, you should learn how to use a debugger such as GDB, and use it to step through the execution of your program, and check the value of variables.

Comment: I usually just try to run the program after i add something new to see if i get errors and thanks ill check GDB out

Answer (score 2):

In your `scanf` statements, you're trying to interpret the input values as `double` (`%lf`).  You, instead, should be reading in integers because you declared all your variables as `int`.  Use `%d` like so:

```
scanf("%d", &number_of_pennies);
```

If you're still confused, read up on [`printf` formating specifications](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf).

Comment: I feel even stupider now because i actually knew the difference for that. Thank you so much!